# How to copy color from webpage to Blender material surface color input value?

Tags: materials

Sometimes I see a nice color I like online and I'd like to be able to copy that color to an object in Blender.
I did try Firefox> Tools> Web Developer> Eyedropper to copy hex value,
but upon pasting into Blender material color field the color changes to something completely different than what I copied.
Just wondering if there's an easy way I'm overlooking.
Blender eyedropper only seems to work when clicking something inside Blender.
Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Load an image in Image editor. Use the color picker to sample the color from the image.
All the objects are affected by the light. It will never be the same as sampled because the light and shadows. You have to play with lights and its RGB or HSV values to get close as possible.

[image]

Comment: Okay thanks for the ideas. So I guess no way other than to actually load an image. I thought maybe a paste of a hex color value but that seems to produce very different color than what I copied from website image, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also load the Image/page here (http://imagecolorpicker.com/) and pick the colour. Then copy the hex-data and paste it in Blender

Comment: Thanks, this got me looking more into maybe I was doing something wrong, and it turns out I was. Without checking to carefully I just pasted the hex value into Blender. Turns out in Blender's color hex value field it has to be just the characters without the #. I was pasting it in with the # and it was cutting off the last letter of the hex value. So thanks, this kept me going in the right direction. Works fine now when I properly paste in the 6 character hex value without the #.